# How to test if a class is abstract in C# in .NET 2?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET 4.5, testing if a type is abstract is as easy as `type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract`. The `GetTypeInfo` API is not available in .NET 2. What's the way to test for abstractness with .NET 2?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isabstract(v=vs.80).aspx) clearly says it is availble in .NET 2.

Comment: @Eminem: that's in the `Type` class, not `TypeInfo`. Still means that no research was done though.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - actually not true, I researched quite a bit, but obviously not in the right place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Type.IsAbstract Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isabstract(v=vs.80).aspx) which is available in .Net 2.0 also.

> Gets a value indicating whether the Type is abstract and must be
>   overridden.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing it wrong way, you need to do the following line:

```
Type myTypeObj = Type.GetType("MyClass");
bool IsAbstract = myTypeObj.IsAbstract;
```